# Probability of an Elevator directly stopping at Floor x

Tags: probability

You are standing on the ground floor of an N-floor building. 

You want to get to the floor **X** (*X is less than or equal to N*). 
Currently, the elevator is on the ground floor itself.
What is the probability that the elevator directly stops at floor **X** without stopping at any of the intermediate floors between the ground floor and the floor **X**? 
The elevator will stop at any of the intermediate floors if someone from outside of the lift presses the intermediate floor button.

So far I have figured out that the Sample-set over here is the number of combinations possible from considering all the floors between the ground floor and the floor **X**.

Hence,

```
Probability of an Event =   Number favorable Outcomes / Total Number of Possible Outcomes

Number favorable Outcomes = 1 (when the elevator directly goes to the floor X)

Total Number of Possible Outcomes = 2 ^ X (Total possible combinations till X)
```

Is this the right approach? And, how do I proceed further?

**Edit**: 
The ground floor starts from **0**.
No one can exit the elevator at the ground floor
There's just a single person entering the elevator from the ground floor, which is you.
Hence, only people from outside can press the intermediate floor button
The elevator can only go downwards once it reaches the topmost floor

Comment: This problem is not well-defined. Based on your assumptions for the "Total Number of Possible Outcomes", you are treating it as though a floor may be pressed or not pressed with equal probability. So, there is as much of a chance that a person presses the button for a lower floor as does not? Without knowing the probability that an individual button will be pressed, there is no way to answer this.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe I have added further details, please have a look. Thanks

Comment: You now say the only person in the building is you on the ground floor, so there is a zero percent chance that anyone else will press a button, and a 100% chance that you will go directly to your floor.

Comment: It depends on the probability people push buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems ill posed because you have not indicated whether or not anyone is getting on the lift with you initially. Additionally, I would argue that it is less likely for someone on an intermediate floor to ride an elevator up (although I can imagine scenarios where it does happen). Finally, there is some discrepancy whether the ground floor is floor $0$ or floor $1$ (In the US, it is floor $1$ while in Europe it is floor $0$). Basically, you have to rigorously define what it means for "any of the intermediate floors if someone from inside or outside of the lift presses the intermediate floor button" and then you're problem can be solved.

Comment: I have added further details, hope that helps. Thanks